# Перестаёт работать OpenCV после установки EasyOCR

Tags: python, opencv

Используя OpenCV всё было хорошо. С его помощью работал с видеокамерой и обрабатывал изображение. Никаких ошибок не было. Появилась необходимость поставить EasyOCR для дальнейшего распознавания текста на обработанном изображении, но после его установки OpenCV показывает ошибки на каждую строку кода с его участием.
Пробовал устанавливать в разных порядках, но ничего не меняется. Проблема появляется ИМЕННО после установки EasyOCR, в коде ничего не меняется.
Пример ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Roman/PycharmProjects/test2105/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Они всегда схожи по последней строчке ошибки, меняется только линия кода. Использую Pyharm. Устанавливал через терминал:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
pip3 install easyocr
```

На всякий случай вот весь код программы:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import easyocr


# Все параметры камеры
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 24) # Частота кадров
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280) # Ширина кадров в видеопотоке.
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720) # Высота кадров в видеопотоке.


# img / gray / thresh / cnts / img

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    # Поиск контуров и сортировка
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

    # Поиск рамки
    for c in cnts:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        ROI = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        break

    cv2.imshow('ROI', thresh)
    cv2.imwrite('ROI.png', thresh)

    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27: # Клавиша Esc
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мною было выяснено, что EasyOCR и OpenCV действительно имеют проблемы в работе друг с другом. Решением стала установка определенной версии OpenCV

```
pip install opencv-python==4.5.4.60
```

Ошибки пропали, программа заработала.